# Jabber Psi+ message history

Tags: jabber

There's openfire-4.0.2 IM sender connected to Samba AD server. As a jabber client Psi+ v0.16.330 is used.

When User1 sends message to User2 this outgoing message doesn't written to User's1 message history. But User2 in *his* history has message from User1. In other words, all histories of all users contains *only* incoming messages, not the full "dialog".

In "Account" settings in Psi+ checkbox "Keep history" is on. "History Keeper" plugin is turned off.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well, don't know, whether this is a bug or feature, but such mess with chat/message history is done by Psi+ client.